# Multiple concurrent downloads from a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

**Background**

We have a website that delivers dynamic content via download to our customers. Currently this is done by simply making a request to another page which dynamically sets the response ContentType and streams out the file data.

**The Problem**

We have now been tasked with delivering multiple pieces of content at once at the click of a button (or as a page loads). We have tried various approaches:

1) Multiple iFrames on the page with a different download URL in each. This did not work in all browsers, and since our platform is targeted at mobile phones, many of the native phone browsers did not handle the iFrames at all.

2) Multiple AJAX requests for the content. This is flawed as the AJAX requests were simply returning the binary data and the page was trying to output all of this onto the page rather than deliver as a download.

3) Multiple JavaScript timeouts. This worked for up to 3 downloads, but was very unreliable because if the second Timeout function begun before the first one had started the download, then the whole thing would simply break and not continue.

At this point I'm fresh out of ideas. I tried Googling for similar solutions to the problem but didn't come up with anything and I'm starting to think that it's actually just not possible.

Note that since the content is target at mobile devices, zipping the files up and delivering all at once is not an option since the devices are often unable to decompress the content.

The question, then, is: Is there a way to reliably trigger a web browser to download multiple pieces of content at once?

Comment: One solution that we use is to compile all of the files we wish to send to the client in a zip file and then stream that out. To date I have not found a satisfactory cross-browser solution to outputting multiple files to a browser.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not suit our needs as we need to deliver the content to mobile devices which oftentimes are unable to decompress the zip files. I will update my question.

Comment: I have just found this link. Maybe this would help as it looks like someone at the bottom of the thread has a solution http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?100258-Download-Multiple-Files-with-Asp-net

Comment: Thanks. We'll give this a go and I'll let you know.

Comment: It turns out that this really isn't possible on mobile devices. Most mobile browsers support the methods involved, but due to the way that each tab of a browser is threaded and paused, it was only possible to fire one download at a time, since any redirect action would interrupt the remaining javascript from processing.

Comment: @aaroncatlin That's a legitimate answer to your question. You should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Have you thought of using http://socket.io/ for streaming your content? Have a look at their site for supported platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this really isn't possible on mobile devices. Most mobile browsers support the methods involved, but due to the way that each tab of a browser is threaded and paused, it was only possible to fire one download at a time, since any redirect action would interrupt the remaining javascript from processing.